# Most performant way to build object from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Currently, I'm building an object from an array of objects with the following:

```
var popOverOptions = {
  defaultOption: true
}

if (a) {
  options.push({a: "b"});
}

if (c) {
  options.push({c: "d"});
}

// Loop through array of objects
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
   // Add objects in array to popoverOptions object
   for (key in options[i]) {
     popoverOptions[key] = options[i][key]
   }
}
```

I'm thinking this could be optimized and I'm curious if there is a better way to write this, possibly using .reduce(), .forEach() or some other method.

Comment: You are iterating each option just once, so unless you are repeating keys in those options, there shouldn´t be a more performant way, just a shorter version

Comment: Two minor optimizations come to mind:

1. If there's a canonical list of attributes to be copied, iterate over these and then search the array for that attribute
2. If there's a canonical list and the last appearance wins, search from the end of the array and break once you find an appearance.

Fundamentally, you need to check every object in at least some cases, so I don't see an obvious way to significantly improve efficiency.

Comment: 1) Worry about performance when it becomes an issue. 2) A `for` loop is about as performant as you can get when looping over an array. The only thing that is faster is no loop (unrolled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ECMAScript 6, you can use

- [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy the properties to `popOverOptions`
- The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to expand the `options` array.

```js
Object.assign(popOverOptions, ...options);
```

Comment: Note `Object.assign` only copies own properties, but your `for...in` loop also iterates inherited ones. Not sure if it's a problem.

Comment: Shorter, yes. More performant, not even close. In the only browser that currently supports `Object.assign` (Firefox 35+), this is about 45% slower than using a regular for loop - http://jsperf.com/loop-versus-assign/2

Comment: @Adam On my Nightly 39, a loop is 42% slower than `Object.assign`. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8M1Tt.png)

Comment: Ah, I was looking at Object.assign at one point, forgot about it though. Thanks for the info and thanks Adam for the jsperf link, good to know.

Comment: @Oriol - I hope I'm not offending you, but are you sure you're reading the results correctly?

Comment: @Oriol - astounding change with the nightly version.

Comment: I ran the jsperf test in Nightly 39.0a1 and am seeing Object.assign having better perf compared to the for loop, the loop is 25% slower, however in Firefox 36.0.4, Object.assign is 48% slower. Interesting to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimise the loop itself like this:

```
for (var i=0, n=options.length; i<n; ++i) {
```

This reduces the number of times you need to access options.length which is slower than reading it from a local.

A smaller optimisation:

```
for (var i=options.length-1; i--; /* empty */) {
```

Source: http://www.phpied.com/extreme-javascript-optimization/

Comment: The last time I measured it, caching the length had the same performance on Chrome, and a worse performance on Firefox.

Comment: @Oriol, this jsPerf shows a *slight* performance increase using caching in Chrome:  https://jsperf.com/array-length-vs-cached

Answer (score 0):

You can cache `length` for a slight speed improvement.

If the keys in your array are identical for each element, you can get twice the speed (in Chrome) by caching `Object.keys(options[0])`, and iterating through that.

Even if the keys *aren't* the same, you can still get approx. 25% increase in speed by iterating through `Object.keys(options[i])`.

```js
var options= [];

for(var i = 0 ; i <= 1000 ; i++) {  //create array of objects with random numbers
  options[i]= {};
  for(var j = 0 ; j <= 5000 ; j++) {
    options[i][j]= Math.random();
  }
}

var popOverOptions = {};

function keyin() {
  var timer= new Date();
  for(var i = 0, leni = options.length ; i < leni; i++) {
    for(var key in options[i]) {
      popOverOptions[key] = options[i][key];
    }
  }
  alert((new Date()-timer)/1000+' seconds');
} //keyin

function objkeys(same) {
  var timer= new Date(),
      keys= Object.keys(options[0]);

  for(var i = 0, leni = options.length ; i < leni; i++) {
    if(!same) keys= Object.keys(options[i]);
    for(var key = 0, lenk = keys.length ; key < lenk ; key++) {
      popOverOptions[keys[key]] = options[i][keys[key]];
    }
  }
  alert((new Date()-timer)/1000+' seconds');
} //objkeys
```

```html
<button onclick="keyin()">key in options</button><br>
<button onclick="objkeys(true)">Object.keys, same keys per element</button><br>
<button onclick="objkeys(false)">Object.keys, different keys per element</button>
```